# MVC4 Default Routes

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, routes

I have the following two routes and when a user lands on the home page, it throws a 404.  Is there something blindingly obvious I'm missing?  I would like them to go to the Home controller...

```
        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "Home/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
            namespaces: new[] { "Coin.Web.Controllers" }
        );

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Organization",
            url: "{organization}/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Dashboard", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
            namespaces: new[] { "Coin.Web.Controllers" }
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Without knowing what the url is you're trying to use, it's hard to be sure what is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the route `/` will miss on the "Default" route (since it will need a `/Home` segment in the URL) the way you have it set up and it will also miss the "Organization" route (since you have no default organization defined). This is why you are getting a 404.

You could fix it by explicitly adding a route for the home page:

```
    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Home",
        url: "",
        defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" },
        namespaces: new[] { "Coin.Web.Controllers" }
    );

    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Default",
        url: "Home/{action}/{id}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
        namespaces: new[] { "Coin.Web.Controllers" }
    );

    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Organization",
        url: "{organization}/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Dashboard", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
        namespaces: new[] { "Coin.Web.Controllers" }
```

FYI - it is typically better to put the more specific routes first before the less specific ones. That is, the "Organization" route should go first and you should leave the "Default" route alone. But you will need to define an explicit segment or a constraint to force a miss on the "Organization" route or use multiple organization routes in order to make that work.